# Taxonomy filter. List terms with ajax checkbox selection

Tags: taxonomy-terms, ajax

I need help to make some filter. 
Block with taxonomy terms list and checkbox selection closure. Checkbox need to return all nodes categorized by selected terms on change. It has to be transparent for user (Ajax).
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use combination of next modules:

- [Better Exposed Filters](http://drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters) - module replaces the Views' default single- or multi-select boxes with radio buttons or checkboxes, respectively.
- [Views Filters Auto-submit (views_filters_autosubmit)](http://drupal.org/project/views_hacks#views_filters_autosubmit) - auto-submits exposed filters on change.